# Apply local commit to new branch

Tags: git, branch, commit

I made some local changes to a branch and committed them locally. They've not been pushed but I have now (after committing) realized, that the remote branch has been deleted, now I would like to apply this commit to a new branch that I then can push upstream. How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you have trouble with? How to create a new branch? How to push a branch? Do you want to rebase the commit?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll just push your local branch again git will recreate it in origin.

If you don't want to create a new remote branch(recreate removed one)  but make your changes on another branch instead you may want to cherry-pick your commits from the old branch to the new one (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).